# Make Dictionary conform to value type protocol

Tags: swift

This is simplified code that doesn't compile. Is there anyway to make this work in Swift? Thanks.

```
protocol Person {

    var name:String { get }

    var age:Int { get }

}

extension Dictionary : Person {

    var name: String {

        return self["name"] as String

    }

    var age: Int {

        return self["Int"] as Int

    }

}
```

Let me give some context to why I would want to do this.

Lets say I have some person data coming in over the wire as json. As I pass it through JSONSerialization I get a [String:AnyObject] Dictionary back.

So I would like to declare the JSON data interfaces in protocols, make the dictionary objects conform to the protocols and then extract the values from the dictionaries via typed properties, rather then via magic strings and casts. This way the client code would only know about protocol types even though they are implemented as dictionaries behind the curtain.

Not sure it's doable or a good idea, just wanted to try it. But compiler is giving me all sorts of trouble.

Comment: You want to make every `Dictionary` ever a `Person`? Why? (There's no conditional conformance in Swift yet). Surely this would be an ideal case where a struct should be used in the first place rather than a dictionary.

Comment: Future developers who need to work at this code will have a lot of fun :)

Comment: Make a struct instead.

Comment: Added some context in the question. It may be a bad idea. Just wanted to try something to make json parsing a little more encapsulated.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to encapsulate the logic to link a json to it's model representation.

### The suggested solution

First of all I am suggesting another way to achieve what you are looking for instead

Look at this Struct.

```
struct Person {
    let name: String
    let age: Int

    init?(json: [String:Any]) {
        guard let name = json["name"] as? String, age = json["age"] as? Int else { return nil }
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}
```

The logic to extract data from the json is encapsulated into its initializer. And if the provided json is not valid the initialization fails. It's safe because it will never crash and it's easy to use.

### The direct answer (don't do this at home!)

```
protocol Person {
    var name: String? { get }
    var age: Int? { get }
}

extension Dictionary : Person {
    private var dictWithStringKeys: [String:Any] {
        return reduce([String:Any]()) { (dict, elm) -> [String:Any] in
            var dict = dict
            if let key = elm.0 as? String {
                dict[key] = elm.1
            }
            return dict
        }
    }

    var name: String? {
        return dictWithStringKeys["name"] as? String
    }

    var age: Int? {
        return dictWithStringKeys["age"] as? Int
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice take on the problem! Thanks.

Comment: @weenzeel: I also provided the direct answer to your question, please check it out

Comment: thanks @appzYourLife. I've tried to set a restriction on my extension only applying it to dictionaries with string keys. But then I can't figure out how to mark the dictionary as also implementing the protocol. Do you know if that is possible? Restricting and implementing at the same time?

Comment: @weenzeel: You cannot add protocol conformance only when specific conditions are satisfied. A type does or does not conform to a protocol.